# S3に画像ファイルをアップロードできない

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, aws, amazon-s3

※[他質問サイト](https://teratail.com/questions/3aylzv3ia4g0s8)でも同様の質問をしています。解決した場合はそちらも更新します。よろしくお願いします。

#### 前提

railsでDM機能を作成しています。
ActiveStorageを使用してS3に画像ファイルをアップロードし、送信した画像を表示したいのですが、実装中に以下のエラーメッセージが発生しました。

ActiveStorage、S3のセットアップは以下を参考にして設定しました。
https://zenn.dev/kurao/articles/ce8e583450c76e

#### 実現したいこと

メッセージフォームから送信した画像をメッセージ一覧に表示したい。

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

```
localhost:3000の内容
Error storing "（ファイル名）". Status: 0
```

メッセージフォームから画像を選択して送信を押すと、このようなエラーメッセージがポップアップで表示され、画像をアップロードできません。

#### 該当のソースコード

```
config/environment/development.rb

Rails.application.configure do
  # ...
    
  config.active_storage.service = :amazon

  # ...

  Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host] = 'localhost'
  Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:port] = 3001  
end
```

```
db/migrate/(日付)_create_active_storage_tables.active_storage.rb

class CreateActiveStorageTables < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :active_storage_blobs do |t|
      t.string   :key,        null: false
      t.string   :filename,   null: false
      t.string   :content_type
      t.text     :metadata
      t.bigint   :byte_size,  null: false
      t.string   :checksum,   null: false
      t.datetime :created_at, null: false

      t.index [ :key ], unique: true
    end

    create_table :active_storage_attachments do |t|
      t.string     :name,     null: false
      t.references :record,   null: false, polymorphic: true, index: false
      t.references :blob,     null: false

      t.datetime :created_at, null: false

      t.index [ :record_type, :record_id, :name, :blob_id ], name: "index_active_storage_attachments_uniqueness", unique: true
      t.foreign_key :active_storage_blobs, column: :blob_id
    end
  end
end
```

```
config/storage.yml

amazon:
  service: S3
  access_key_id: <%= Rails.application.credentials.dig(:aws, :access_key_id) %>
  secret_access_key: <%= Rails.application.credentials.dig(:aws, :secret_access_key) %>
  region: <%= Rails.application.credentials.dig(:aws, :s3, :region) %>
  bucket: <%= Rails.application.credentials.dig(:aws, :s3, :bucket) %>
```

```
app/models/message.rb

class Message < ApplicationRecord
（省略）
  has_one_attached :image
end
```

```
app/views/rooms/show.html.erb

<div class="row my-5">
（省略）
  <% if @messages.present? %>
（省略）
<!-- 画像を表示するコード -->
    <%= image_tag @message.image.variant(resize:'500x500'), class: 'message-image' if @message.image.attached? %>
<!--  -->

  <% else %>
    <p>メッセージはまだありません。</p>
  <% end %>


  <%= form_with model: @message do |f| %>
（省略）
<!-- 画像を選択するコード -->
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.file_field :images, direct_upload: true, multiple: true %>
    </div>
<!--  -->

    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.submit "送信", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

```
messages_controller.rb

class MessagesController < ApplicationController

  def create
    if Entry.where(user_id: current_user.id, room_id: params[:message][:room_id]).present?
      @message = Message.new(message_params)
      if @message.save
        redirect_to "/rooms/#{@message.room_id}"
      end
    else
      flash[:alert] = "メッセージ送信に失敗しました。"
    end
  end

  private

  def message_params
    params.require(:message).permit(:user_id, :content, :image, :room_id).merge(user_id: current_user.id)
  end
end
```

#### 試したこと

ActiveStorage、S3のセットアップに問題があると思い、エラーメッセージを検索しましたが、該当するページが見当たらず、お力添えをいただきたいです。

#### 補足情報（FW/ツールのバージョンなど）

ruby '3.0.2'
rails ' 6.0.4'

#### -追記（20220329）

@messageがsaveされる前にbinging.pryを設置してエラーをチェックした結果、以下が表示されました。
※一部伏せ字にしています。

```
Started POST "/rails/active_storage/direct_uploads" for 192.168.160.1 at <日時> +0000
Cannot render console from 192.168.160.1! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255, ::1
Processing by ActiveStorage::DirectUploadsController#create as JSON
Parameters:
{
"blob" => {
"filename" => "<ファイル名>",
"content_type" => "image/png",
"byte_size" => 30047,
"checksum" => "<checksumの文字列>"
},
"direct_upload" => {
"blob" => {
"filename" => "<ファイル名>",

"content_type" => "image/png",
"byte_size" => 30047,
"checksum" => "<checksumの文字列>"
}
}
}
(0.6ms)
BEGIN
ActiveStorage::Blob Create (1.3ms)
INSERT
INTO
`active_storage_blobs` (
`key`
,`filename`
,`content_type`
,`byte_size`
,`checksum`
,`created_at`
)
VALUES (
'<キー>'
,'<ファイル名>'
,'image/png'
,30047
,'<checksumの文字列>'
,'<日時>'
)
(5.8ms)
COMMIT
S3 Storage (1.6ms) Generated URL for file at key: <キー> (https://<バケット名>.s3.<リージョン名>.amazonaws.com/<キー>?X-Amz
-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=<アクセスキーID>%2F<日付>%2F<リージョン名>%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=<日付>T<時間>Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Signe
dHeaders=content-length%3Bcontent-md5%3Bcontent-type%3Bhost&X-Amz-Signature=01c10359b86d5cf1ef020d0286e428762f907fd7d6a7db1b8a2ed0c5daf08c8e)
Completed 200 OK in 1043ms (Views: 0.7ms | ActiveRecord: 12.0ms | Allocations: 231324)
```

以上

Cannot render console from <IPアドレス>! のエラーが出ていましたので、以下記事を参考に
`config/environment/development.rb`にホワイトリストを追記しましたが、同様のエラーが表示され解決に至りませんでした。
https://qiita.com/terufumi1122/items/73da039e6fc90ee0a63f

↓追記したホワイトリスト

```
Rails.application.configure do
  config.web_console.whitelisted_ips = '192.168.160.1'
（略）
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

以下にて解決いたしました。

- config.web_console.whitelisted_ipsでRailsへの許可設定
  development.rbに`config.web_console.whitelisted_ips = '0.0.0.0/0'`を追加
- S3バケットにCORSの設定
  以下の記事を参考にしています。

  [CORS（Cross-Origin Resource Sharing）を設定する - Railsガイド](https://railsguides.jp/active_storage_overview.html#cors%EF%BC%88cross-origin-resource-sharing%EF%BC%89%E3%82%92%E8%A8%AD%E5%AE%9A%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B)

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET",
            "POST",
            "HEAD",
            "PUT"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": [],
        "MaxAgeSeconds": 3000
    }
]
```